# Prime Elements and irreducible elements in the ring ${C}[0,1]$

Tags: ring-theory

What are the prime elements and the irreducible elements in the ring of real valued continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$? 
How to find those?

I know the prime ideals and maximal ideals in this ring but I need help with finding the prime elements and the irreducible elements.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh wow, that's a major lapse of judgment. I'll go grab my coffee

Comment: @DonThousand every element has a cube root in the ring, so clearly the conclusion about no irreducible elements is true. I’m not used to working with primes in nondomains though.  No insight yet there.

Comment: @DonThousand. Yes you're right. No need to think about primes. But didn't get what you said about irreducibles.